# Creating a webservice best practise?

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl

Currently I'm experimenting on creating a webservice which should be the point of entry for third parties to my system. After reading some info I got started on creating my testservice.

At first I started with the PEAR package but I found it to be too much of a hassle to define the service (with the `__typedef` and `__dispatch_map`) so I looked further. I came across my initial resource, php's native SoapServer. This looks a lot cleaner because functions area easily defined but I need to define the WSDL. This is where I get stuck. Is there a simple way to create a WSDL by telling the generator which functions/methods are available, which parameters they expect and what the returnvalue is?

Comment: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/3509-PHP-Generate-WSDL-from-PHP-classes-code.html

Comment: @Price, why did you edit my post?

Comment: @BenFransen he removed "Thanks in advance" and your name because [they are not allowed in SO questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/164291).

Comment: @Phoenix, okay. I personally think it's a respectful start for a question rather than just putting my 'shout for help' on the forum. But if these are the rules, I'll respect them from now.

Answer (score 4):

Slim framework is used to create RESTful web applications. The Slim micro framework is everything you need and nothing you don't.

http://www.slimframework.com/

This is the best one i found in the market.

Comment: cute.  good link!  however, isn't the requester asking for something related to SOAP and not REST?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, +1! @Sdolgy, I was asking for SOAP because that seemed to be the way. Currently I'm also exploring this option.

Answer (score 1):

I found Zend Autodiscovery to be very helpful when trying to avoid all the hustle that come with creating WSDL files. Zend is famously used as a framework but you can also use it as a library if you want to maintain a standalone application. Check it out at:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.soap.autodiscovery.html

Having said that, there are many ways to implement web services so I suggest you have a look at other options before settling on SOAP. I personally feel that REST is brilliant.

Comment: one issue with Zend is how incredibly large and bloated it is.  it can do anything ... which is good, and bad.

Comment: point taken, but thats why I pointed out that you can use it as a library if you wish to run a stand alone application.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Atm I'm using SOAP with the class mentioned in the comment to my question. +1. I know Zend Framework is large, I think too large for our custom made framework to integrate well.

Answer (score 0):

The Nusoap PHP tool (actually, library), automatically generates the WSDL for you.
Obviously you have to write some code that explain to Nusoap what are the types of your data. It also handle custom, complex data.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/nusoap/

It also come with plentiful of examples...